# fatal: protocol 'https' is not supported, Git

Tags: git, git-push

estoy intentando de hacer un "git push origin main", pero a la hora de hacerlo me responde con lo siguiente:

```
fatal: protocol 'https' is not supported
```

he intentado varios comandos pero todavia no me sale nada

Comment: Probablemente hay un error en el URL que quedó para el repositorio. Verifica que el URL esté bien definido en el archivo de configuración con un editor de texto (o sea, en el archivo `.git/config`)

Comment: muchas gracias @eftshift0 ,exactamente era la url que estaba mal,lo arregle ahora funciona bien